# How do I remove ValueEventListener in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I have been working with firebase for 2 weeks. Please I need your help.

```
   public void closeReadRef() {
    if (readRef != null)
        readRef.removeEventListener(listener);
}
```

That code above has to remove my listener but it is not working. I call this method in `onPause`, `onDestroy`, `onStop`:

```
    @Override
public void onStart() {
    FirebaseUtility.getInstance().closeReadRef();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Why can I not cancel the listener?
Thank you.

**EDIT**

I call this below method in onCreate() inside an Activity.

```
 public void setReadTrueInFireBase(final String currentID, final String location) {
    instance.currentID = currentID;
    instance.location = location;
    readRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(Constant.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL);
    readRef.child("conversations").child(location).addValueEventListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: Where did you place the `addValueEventListener` or `addChildEventListener`? And maybe show us code where `listener` object is created.

Comment: sorry @koceeng I will add it.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference readRef;
ValueEventListener listener;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    readRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(Constant.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL);
    listener = readRef.child("conversations").child(location).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                /* ... */
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                /* .... */
            }
        });
 }

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (readRef != null && listener != null) {
        readRef.removeEventListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

databaserefercence.removeEventListener(listener);

u need to save the added listener in a variable